# Combine two functions into one

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, merge

The goal here is to create one function from 2 functions with **argument combination**. It could be easily done with JavaScript, but it's not easy with typescript.

One way to combine two functions is **Proxy**. Example:

```js
const f1 = (a: number) => {
    return (a + 1) * 2;
} 

const f2 = (b: string, c: string[]) => {
    c.push(b);
    return c;
}

const combiner = (f1: Function, f2: Function) => {
    return new Proxy(f1, {
        apply(target, thisArg, args) {
            const f1_args = args.slice(0, f1.length);
            const f2_args = args.splice(f1.length);
            f1(...f1_args);
            f2(...f2_args);
        }
    });
};

const f = combiner(f1, f2);

f(1, 'foo', ['bar']); // Typehints?
```

The question is **could it be typed with typescript to typehint result of `combiner` function?**

Comment: Can you elaborate on "create one function from 2 functions"? What would the return value be of the "combined" function? Can you include your solution that's "easily done with JavaScript"?

Comment: Return type doesn't matter at all. It depends on what you want from this code. It can be `void` like in my example or any other type.

Comment: Solution for JavaScript in example. It's working

Comment: I want typehints for code like `f(1, 'foo', ['bar'])` that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing the parameters of the combined function is trivially achieved by using two generic types `A1` and `A2` which hold the parameter tuple types of the two functions.

```
const combiner = <
  A1 extends any[], 
  A2 extends any[]
>(f1: (...args: A1) => void, f2: (...args: A2) => void) => {
    return new Proxy(f1, {
        apply(target, thisArg, args) {
            const f1_args = args.slice(0, f1.length);
            const f2_args = args.splice(f1.length);
            f1(...f1_args as A1);
            f2(...f2_args as A2);
        }
    }) as unknown as (...args: [...A1, ...A2]) => void
};
```

We only need to assert that the returned type is a function which has the combined `A1` and `A2` tuples as its parameter type.

```
const f = combiner(f1, f2);
//    ^? const f: (a: number, b: string, c: string[]) => void

f(1, 'foo', ['bar']);
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgRhgXhgCgIYC4ZgK4C2ARgKYBOAlCgHwwDeAUDMzGSVHmWOhjANQwEVAFQwATAG4GAXxgMGoSLDhiU6IjmhkAlmADmAGhjBNUHfoDaAXSrJajFsYB0ABzwQAFmiIUpjthxcxlLS8orQxiDEuuRqADxMMACCSCQAHlAkYAAmEDAYYACe1kaJSarpmTl5BcVWDNRoiDhoTm0YZHoQOCm2tABuINrZRiotbU4dXT1ifTCDw3MOLAGc3GAkAO4wAApkIGmFTQhGy47MGC4uADZHUFPsRlAe2hBJnUZTEFRn547hygQAH0vmovk4INdtMASGgAAyjBBOa5ZPTPXyJP7-cARFQgzp5VDgiA3aGwxDI1HovxYxyIVptRD4rr5PK9Gm05gqBlOPGgjBs2Yc86hRzSKgCmB4MAAazAIE23ElPK+OAsExSRg1YhsNHmQ2yMikChxyjUoGiGzIx1GQoYAHp7Y4AHoAfkiSngLWwuEIpDIRg0MC0ukMxlM5j01jmC0NDDgaBOMAA5HAQCBk0YLMmiB1kzYJEA)